# R: subset from a matrix only those rows with a certain value in a certain column

Tags: r, loops, subset

I have a large matrix "dt" of emergency department visits over 2 months for a set of diagnosis codes. The columns are "age", "sex", "date", "county", "zip", "subjectid", "position", "diag", and "dt"; the dimensions are 872344 by 9.

I want to subset from this matrix and make a new matrix containing only those rows for which the "diag" column has a number between 800 and 849 (all columns).

I have been messing with building a loop and using "which" or "if.else" but I'm running into a mental block. It seems it would be easier if it was just ONE diag code that I wanted to pull out, but the series of 50 codes complicates things... pointing to a loop? Does anyone have ideas for how to subset based on finding certain values?

Here's my start (it didn't work):

```
dta = dt
b = 800:849
for (i in 1:length(b)) {

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your column names, I suspect your `dt` is a data.frame, not a matrix; something you can confirm by running `is.data.frame(dt)`.

If it is the case, an easy way to filter your data is to use the `subset` function as follows:

```
dta <- subset(dt, diag >= 800 & diag <= 849)
```

Comment: You are right- it is a dataframe.  I guess I never understood the difference in R's language.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

```
dta = dt[dt[, 8] >= 800 & dt[, 8] <= 849, ]
```

ETA: Are you sure this is a matrix and not a data.frame? If it is a data.frame, you can do:

```
dta = dt[dt$diag >= 800 & dt$diag <= 849, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to excellent answers above, I can add `filter` function in `dpylr` package

```
filter(dt,diag>=800 & diag <= 849)
```

`filter()` is similar to `subset()` except that you can give it any number of filtering conditions, which are joined together with `&` (not `&&` which is easy to do accidentally!). `dpylr` package also has other nice data manipulating functions which you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I would not convert the `matrix()` to a `data.frame()` as it is slower and incurs greater memory usage, while `matrix()` operations are generally faster anyway.

In addition to David's answer using column number indexing:

```
dta = dt[dt[,8] >= 800 & dt[,8] <= 849,]
```

There is also the form using column name indexing with a matrix:

```
dta = dt[dt[,'metric'] >= 800 & dt[,'metric'] <= 849,]
```

As shown by the `microbenchmark` package command for an identical matrix with 12 columns and 13,241 rows, run with R compiled with Intel MKL optimization:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
     test.matrix     = mt[mt[,3] %in% 5:10 & mt[,5] == 1,],
     test.data.frame = df[df[,3] %in% 5:10 & df[,5] == 1,],
     times = 1000
     )

Unit: microseconds
            expr      min       lq     mean  median        uq        max neval
 test.matrix      885.732  938.386 1154.898  943.74  952.4415 138215.318  1000
 test.data.frame 1176.218 1245.826 1363.379 1258.32 1286.4320 3392.556    1000
```

When the matrices get very large, this difference becomes tangible. On my machine, matrix indexing speeds outperform those of `data.table` as well.